# Can I use libgdx for scientific computing and UI on Android?

Tags: android-widget, scientific-computing, libgdx

I'm making an app that is an interactive mathematical visualization based on a real-time stream of data. Libgdx was recommended to me to deal with the intricate, real-time graphics, but I do also need to do scientific computing and require some UI like buttons and drop-down lists. Can I do this using libgdx, or a combination of libgdx and SDK/NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining libgdx directly with SDK is not supported yet, I believe. Of course you can have different activites using either SDK or libgdx, but this is not what you need. However, libgdx comes with [Themable Widget Library](http://twl.l33tlabs.org/), which has support for most of the basic UI features, which depending on your specific requirements may or may not fullfill your needs.

Just check out libgdx from svn:

> svn checkout http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ libgdx-read-only

all other extensions beside TWL are also included in the repo (they are not included in zip file downloadable from libgdx homepage download page, i think). After building, you get necessary jars and can start using TWL with libgdx right away.

Here is also the simple [libgdx+TWL](http://dpk.net/2011/03/10/libgdx-and-twl/) example for getting started.